# WalletConnect Mobile Linking

Tags: web3js, metamask, android, walletconnect

i have a quite difficult task .
I haven't found tutorial or something with "mobile Linking" with WalletConnect :
https://docs.walletconnect.com/mobile-linking
"In order to add support for mobile linking within your wallet, you will just need to register the following deep link or universal link subscriptions in your mobile app."
Can you please explain me what this mean :
**"For Android**
Android has the easiest integration as its operating system is designed to handle multiple applications subscribing to the same deep linking schema. Hence you will only need to register to the wc: schema that is defined per the WalletConnect URI standard."

And There is an example:

## Example

wc:00e46b69-d0cc-4b3e-b6a2-cee442f97188@1?bridge=https%3A%2F%2Fbridge.walletconnect.org&key=91303dedf64285cbbaf9120f6e9d160a5c8aa3deb67017a3874cd272323f48ae

Comment: What are you writing a wallet or an app?

Answer (score 1):

In Android, a deep link is a link that takes you directly without any prompts, interstitial pages, or logins, to a specific destination within an app. A WalletConnect schema is a set of JSON-RPC 2.0 requests and responses, and WalletConnect will send requests to a wallet and will receive either signed transactions or failures as responses. You can take a look at this tutorial regarding WalletConnect mobile linking with website:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws5jIo4NMDc

Others resources:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250191/deeplinking-to-connect-to-mobile-wallets-using-wallet-connect

Comment: Thanks Yongjipan , i already see this video the problem is that he use to connect with wallet connect but i want to use wallet connect to connect to mobile wallets and not through qr code (when pop ups the qrcode-modal you can chose from mobile /desktop ).
I want to use the mobile part .

Comment: Thanks however , i figure out that i was able just to use this link and configure it out usin this link :
https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/web3-provider#filter-linking-options.
P.S:
If you get some error like this :
"BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default....... etc ."

I just instaled url .
npm install url